# What is the recommended way of running tests when using Microsoft.NET.Build.Containers?

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core

When I have created my own dockerfile I have used build steps to build and test in the same image without building the application multiple times. Is there a recommended approach to how to build and test when using Microsoft.NET.Build.Containers?

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to test using containers, then you'll need to build the test project - and you'll also need to change from using an inferred `ContainerBaseImage` to using an explicit one. Since you'll likely want to test your app using `dotnet test`, you'll need to set `ContainerBaseImage` to an image that contains an SDK install - most likely `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:<SOME_TAG>`. Altogether this might look like adding the following to your test project:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <ContainerBaseImage>mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-preview</ContainerBaseImage>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Having to 'eject' like this feels kind of bad, so we'll likely do some work here to allow you to choose a different Microsoft base image without also having to change the tag you'd like to use.

You'll also want to change the command that's run when you execute the container. Since your test project is already built, you want to run the equivalent of `dotnet test path/to/test/project.dll`. You do this by adding `ContainerEntrypointArgs` to set the command. This looks something like:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <ContainerEntrypointArgs Include="test;$(TargetFileName)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

(`TargetFileName` is an MSBuild property that the SDK has created at this point that points to the expected .dll file for this project).

*However* I'd like to challenge the need to test in containers at all. Most container environments bring overhead that can shorten the test loop - why not test your code in a Linux environment (either in CI or locally via tools like WSL/etc). One of the goals of the containerization effort is to enable developers to stay in the 'native' .NET toolchain as much as possible and not have to eject to isolated environments.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It doesn't have to be done all in the container, what I want to achieve is build once, test it and then create image. How do I achieve that? Can I build and then test with `--no-build` and then do publish with `--no-build`, would that work? I don't think the option you layout is what I want to do since that would result in a larger resulting image if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: You should be able to do that, yes - the caveat would be that I believe we try to publish in a RID-specific manner (so that the container generated is the best possible fit for the runtime environment), so if you don't have `RuntimeIdentifier(s)` set then the `--no-build` argument to publish might fail (since publish tries to do another restore+build if you publish for a RID that wasn't originally part of the restore).

Comment: so if I understand correctly. If the RID is set correctly the --no-build when publish should work so I don't build the code multiple times.